# Very strange way of data processing of handlebars and/or express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I ran into a very strange issue.

My goal: Produce HTML output based on templates in an nodejs/express/handlebars server.

To achieve that my handlebars content templates are constructed in such a way that they define what kind of templates to use for rendering with a tag such as:

```
{{!< articlepage}}
```

So far so good. By accident I specified the template during rendering:

```
res.render(contentID, {
    template: myPage.template,
    title: myPage.title,
    subtitle: myPage.subtitle
    });
```

I accidently deleted the default template because I use explicit information about which template to use. In THAT case I ran into an error. This is the error output:

```
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/proj/myproject/views/layouts/main.hbs'
    at Error (native)
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/proj/myproject/views/layouts/main.hbs'
    at Error (native)
```

I find it hard to believe that the template engine tries to load the (non existent) main template though I specify the template to use explicitely. This would indicate that there is a software design error.

So my question is: Why is the template engine behaving so strangely? Why is it trying to load the default template - TWICE! - though it does not need to use it at all? Does anyone who is a bit more experienced than me regarding express have any information why express is behaving this way?

Comment: How have you defined the `myPage` object? Perhaps you have duplicate values in `template`, `title`, `subtitle`.

Comment: `myPage` is an object serving as a container for key value pairs. `template` is a variable containing the template to use for rendering. (At least I would like to do that.) `title` is some title to display by the template. `subtitle` the subtitle.

Comment: I do not see why duplicate values should be of any issue. The problem is: a) Why does the system attempts to load a template not required? b) Why does the system attempts to do this even twice?

Comment: If you *do* have duplicate values in the `myPage` config, that would be a reason for the server to attempt to load such a file twice.

Comment: In the line above I tell the server to render a single page. The method "render" is called exactly once. There is exactly one "myPage"-Object: It has members that store values for rendering exactly one page. There is no way that this could cause the second loading attempt.

Comment: You're missing the point I was making. If you have for example duplicate values in `myPage.template` *and* `myPage.title`, it would absolutely try to load them twice. Sometimes the simplest things can be spotted with a fresh pair of eyes, which is why I mentioned it. I don't have time to investigate this - good luck with your issue.

Comment: Why would the framework load it twice? "title" is an identifyer I selected for a title within a template as well as subtitle. Is "title" a protected keyword used within handlebars or express? I haven't seen anything in the documentation like this yet. If I missed something please tell me. But I must say it would be a very strange framework if it would load a template not based on the existence of one, but of two identifiers.